# Keychain giving error errSecAuthFailed in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychain

I am trying to use standard code of keychain from Apple's sample code [KeychainTouchID](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014530)

Here is snippet of my code,

```
SecAccessControlRef sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
                                            kSecAccessControlUserPresence, &error);

if (sacObject == NULL || error != NULL) {
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SecItemAdd can't create sacObject: %@", error];

    self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByAppendingString:errorString];

    return;
}

// we want the operation to fail if there is an item which needs authentication so we will use
// kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    (id)kSecClass: (id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
    (id)kSecAttrService: @"SampleService",
    (id)kSecValueData: [@"SECRET_PASSWORD_TEXT" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
    (id)kSecUseAuthenticationUI: (id)kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow,
    (id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject
};

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    OSStatus status =  SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, nil);

    NSString *errorString = [self keychainErrorToString:status];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SecItemAdd status: %@", errorString];

    [self printMessage:message inTextView:self.textView];
});
```

But key chain always returns error `errSecAuthFailed`. Same code is code is working on one device iPhone6+ but it is not working on iPhone5 with iOS 9.x.

Tried a lot to find reason but didn't find anything useful. One important thing that I noted is that if I don't set attributed `kSecAttrAccessControl` then it is working fine on iPhone5 as well. so, I believe it is something related to setting access control attribute.

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: So what exactly is the error? Where does it fail?

Comment: have you set a passcode on the device?